# Apple says the VP9 codec no longer works on Catalina. I want this codec for my older OS. Where can I find it?

Tags: video, quicktime

Apple has a page listing "[Media formats affected by the transition to 64-bit technology](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT209000)":

> In macOS versions up to and including macOS Mojave, third-party software has extended the QuickTime 7 framework to support many incompatible media formats. In macOS Catalina, the QuickTime 7 framework will no longer be available, so incompatible formats won't be supported in Final Cut Pro, Motion and Compressor.

> Here are examples of media formats affected by this transition:

The second item on the list of affected formats reads:

> **AV1 / VP9**

I am on an older version of macOS, and I would *very* much like to have native support for VP9 in QuickTime! Unfortunately, I am not aware of any QuickTime components that add compatibility with VP9. Perian, which is listed seperately, only ever supported up to VP8.

Was there ever a VP9 QuickTime Component, and if not, what is Apple's page referring to? I am looking for the name of the specific software being referenced.

Answer (score 4):

Welp, I'm still not sure whether there ever was a VP9 component, but there is now because I made one. I managed to update FFusion (the core component of Perian) to work with a newer version of libavcodec.

https://github.com/Wowfunhappy/FFusion

At long last, I can watch 4K Youtube videos in QuickTime Player 10.2.

Answer (score 3):

> Was there ever a VP9 codec, and if not, what is Apple's page referring to?

**No**, there is no Quicktime Player plugin that adds VP9 codec support to it (as far as I know). Apple is referring to codecs built on *Quicktime Framework*.

***Quicktime Framework* is a multimedia library** provided on macOS.

The `Quicktime Player` app, `Quicktime Broadcaster`, `QuickTime Streaming Server` etc. all use the *Quicktime framework* to play videos and / or manipulate them (edit or re-encode them).

Many video editors on macOS use the *Quicktime Framework* too, to add support for codecs (like VP9) for use in these video editor apps.

(Note: Codec support added to an app doesn't make it available to ALL apps that use the framework - so for example, Quicktime Player will not be able to automatically use VP9 codec added to another app just because it is using the *Quicktime Framework*).

With macOS Catalina, **Apple has now replaced the old *QuickTime 7 Framework*** with a new *Quicktime X framework*. **Due to this big change, *any codec* built on the old Quicktime 7 Framework will no longer work on macOS Catalina**.

More info here: [Apple is killing QuickTime 7 in macOS 10.15](https://eclecticlight.co/2019/03/23/apple-is-killing-quicktime-7-in-macos-10-15-convert-old-media-now/).

(However, this doesn't mean that VP9 (or other codecs) cannot be used to watch VP9 / webM videos on macOS Catalina. You can still watch VP9 encoded videos using other media players like MPV, [VLC](https://www.videolan.org/) or [IINA](https://iina.io/) on macOS Catalina. You can also create / encode VP9 media with [Handbrake](https://handbrake.fr/) on macOS Catalina.)

Comment: I appreciate the time you put into this, but it doesn't answer my question at all! As you say, Apple's page implies that there were old apps / software that added support for the VP9 codec using the QuickTime 7 framework. _I want to know what app that was_, so I can use it with QuickTime 7 on my old OS. Your answer says there was one—what was it? I can't find anything!

Comment: Updated with better explanation.

Comment: If at all possible, could you please note which app actually used the QuickTime framework for VP9 support? That's the piece I'm really looking for!

Comment: @Wowfunhappy On2 Flix is the only one I recognize, but Google has bought it, and On2's Flix softwares are no longer available.

Comment: But I don't think that could have supported VP9? They were bought in 2010, and VP9 came out in 2013.

Comment: @Wowfunhappy The linked Apple page says they did. Google did buy them because they created the VP codecs.

Answer (score 0):

There were AV1/VP9 QuickTime 7 *framework extensions by third-parties* as clearly stated. There was never an AV1/VP9 VP9 QuickTime 7 *Component*. That is the answer to your question.

It seems you have misunderstood the software architecture by confusing the names together.

To put it briefly,

Quicktime 7 ≠ Quicktime 7 framework ≠ Quicktime 7 framework extensions by third parties ≠ Quicktime 7 Component

Although they are similar and interrelated they are logically, architecturally, and semantically distinct constructs.

For a partial summary see: apple.com/euro/quicktime/pdf/QuickTime7_User_Guide.pdf For the full details, the documentation is not publicly available. They would be internal engineering documents.

On what exactly the difference is:

Though the name is indicative, as a ‘framework extension’ directly extends the framework, i.e augments the framework with some additional capacity that may or may not augment the usable functionality of quicktime itself, whereas a component does augment the usable functionality but may or may not directly extend the framework, it could just plug-and-play into the existing framework.

In regards to specific software, since they were created by third-parties you would have to look up which were involved with Quicktime 7, as far as I know Apple doesn’t have a public list of who did what.

Comment: Could you please explain the difference between a QuickTime 7 Component and a QuickTime 7 Framework Extension? And, what software specifically contained such an extension for AV1/VP9?